# Saving and checking account penalty amount and return balance

Tags: c#

I am a student learning c#. There are some concepts bothering me when I am doing my assignment. This is my assignment.

Any time a deposit is made to the "S" -Savings account, the bank should match 5% of the deposit
Whenever a withdrawl causes the account balance to fall below $0, a penalty should be applied.  The penalty for the "C" -Checking and "S" -Savings account is $20 and $30, respectively.
Display a message to the user when the balance in any of the account goes under $0.  The message should state the account that is in negative.
Display the ending balances for both the accounts to the user after a transaction is completed.

```
abstract class Account
{
    private float balance;
    private float penalty;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your full name: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please enter your account type to create( C -Checking or S -Savings ):");
        string accounttype = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please enter your opening balance: ");
        string openingbalance = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please specify if you are going to deposit or withdrawl(D -Deposit or W -Withdraw):");
        string depositwithdrawl = Console.ReadLine();

        if (accounttype == "S" && depositwithdrawl == "D")
            balance = (1 + 5 %) * openingbalance;

        if balance < 0;
        get { return balance; }
    }

    public class SavingAccount: Account
    {
        public void MakeDeposit(float amount)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }
        public void MakeWithdraw(float amount)
        {
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }

    public class CheckingAccount: Account
    {
        public void MakeDeposit(float amount)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }
        public void MakeWithdraw(float amount)
        {
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }


    public void ApplyPenalty(float amount)
    {
        if (balance < 0 && accounttype == "S")
            penalty = 30;

        if (balance < 0 && accounttype == "C")
            penalty = 20;
    }


    public void ApplyMethod(float amount)
    {
        if (balance < 0 && accounttype == "S")
            balance = balance-30;

        if (balance < 0 && accounttype == "C")
            balance = balance- 20;
    }

    public float Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
    }
}
```

1. Introduce an abstract class Account.cs
2. Introduce 2 classes that inherit from the Account.cs class (SavingsAccount & CheckingAccount)
3. Have an abstract method MakeDeposit() in the Account.cs class
4. Implement the MakeDeposit() in the derived classes
5. Have an abstract method ApplyPenalty() in the Account.cs class
6. Implement the ApplyMethod() to deduct the penalty amount from the account balance.

I always got the error the 'accounttype' doesn't exist in the current context 
and for the variable balance, an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Account.balance'

Answer (score 1):

Is this your first foray into programming?

First of all, you are getting the compilation error here:

```
if ( balance < 0 && accounttype == "S" )
```

Because "accounttype" is not declared as a member of the Account class; rather, you are declaring it as a local variable further down in your Main() method.

To overcome this, add accounttype as a member, just like balance (we'll get to penalty later):

```
abstract class Account
{
    private float balance;
    private float accounttype;
```

Now, before we get to your second error, you should probably rearrange your code a bit.  I'm assuming you want you created a C# Console Application, that should have a static void Main( string [] args ) method as the starting point of your program.  The problem is that you've encapsulated that Main() method within your Account class, and I don't think that's what you want to do.

Pay attention to the curly braces, and move the Main() method down below the end of your Account class:

Oh yeah, one more thing... I'd recommend using decimal instead of float for monetary values.  The explanation of the previous statement is outside the scope of this textbook.  :)  Just trust me for now.

```
abstract class Account 
{
    private decimal balance;
    private decimal penalty;
    private string accounttype;

    public void MakeDeposit( decimal amount )
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

    // ... and so on

    public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        // This is new too... you'll need this 'set' method here in your Balance property.  More on that later.
        set { balance = value; }
    }
}

// Now we put the Main() method
static void Main( string [] args )
{
    // Your main program code goes here.
}
```

OK! Now that we've got that sorted out, your second error is because you need to *instantiate* (fancy word for "create") an object of one of your derived Account classes (that you have not implemented yet); otherwise, there is nothing that gives the term 'balance' any meaning.  It's an Account that has a balance, after all... not the Main function of your Computer Science 101 program.

Of course, since Account is an *abstract* class, you cannot instantiate an Account object (you'll get a compilation error).  So, you'll need to write code for those derived classes, such as SavingsAccount:

```
// This can probably go after your Account class definition, but just before your Main() method:
class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    // More stuff will go here later
}
```

Now, in your Main() method, you can create an instance (an 'object') of type SavingsAccount, and set its balance... as soon as you clean up some syntax issues with data types and operators.

```
// Bad things here... balance=(1+5%)*openingbalance;
```

You cannot multiply a number and a string together.  You need to convert the string into a number, but take care!  Good programming requires that we save the users from themselves.  You should check that the value they entered for the opening balance is, in fact, a valid decimal.  If it is not, we warn the user and ask them to try again:

```
    bool isBalanceValid = false;
    decimal decOpeningBalance = 0;
    Console.Write("Please enter your opening balance: ");

    while ( ! isBalanceValid )
    {
        string openingbalance = Console.ReadLine();
        if ( ! decimal.TryParse(openingbalance, out decOpeningBalance) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "You must enter a valid decimal value, please try again" );
        }
        else
        {
            isBalanceValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Ok, so back down to where we are assigning the balance to the savings account... C# does not use the '%' sign for decimals, so use 0.05 as 5%:

```
    SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount();

    if ( accounttype == "S" && depositwithdrawl == "D" )
        savingsAccount.Balance = ( 1 + 0.05M ) * decOpeningBalance;
```

I might have gone too far with this explanation, but I'd rather help somebody learn why to code instead of just how to code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and detailed instruction!!! I really appreciate it.